# Чем отличается альфа и бета тестирование в Google Play?

Tags: android, java

Чем отличается альфа и бета тестирование в Google Play?

Answer (score 3):

Альфа тестирование обычно означает тестирование внутри компании или тестирование специальной командой тестеров, а бета тестирование - это тестирование независимыми тестерами (скорее уже потребителями/юзерами).

С точки зрения Google Play надо просто указывать тестеров кому доступны альфа и бета версии аппы.

Comment: Я думал это влияет на покупку товаров...А есть ли способ "бесплатно" тестировать в приложении in-app?

Answer (score 2):

> Я думал это влияет на покупку товаров...А есть ли способ "бесплатно"
>   тестировать в приложении in-app? – 007

Чтобы бесплатно тестировать покупки в Google play нужно добавить аккаунт с которого будет производиться тестовая\ покупка в настройки аккаунта Google Play:
В админской консоли: Настройки(шестеренка) - Сведения об аккаунте - Аккаунты Gmail тестировщиков